# How to figure out scalar data type limits in protobuf

Tags: protocol-buffers

The question basically is: Is there a protobuf equivalent to C++'s `std::numeric_limits<T>::max()`

or `INT_MAX?`

For example, in my .proto file, I have an enum, which I'd like to extend over time, but I also want an "invalid" value for test purposes. Since I want the enum to grow over time, I don't want to just pick a random big value for my invalid entry, as one day, it might become valid. SO I want to pick the absolute maximum of the enum underlying data type, and I'm looking for a well defined method of doing this.

```
// data processing mode
enum CONFIG_DP_mode_id_t {
    CONFIG_DP_RAW      = 0;
    CONFIG_DP_SPEED    = 1;
    CONFIG_DP_ACCURACY = 2;
    CONFIG_DP_CUSTOM   = 3;
    CONFIG_DP_INVALID  = ???
}
```

I've tried just using a manual value (like 0xffffffff for a 32-bit integer), but I don't find that satisfactory. I'd like something that's generated for me by the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer: No, there isn't a direct protobuf equivalent to C++'s std::numeric_limits::max() or INT_MAX for enums.

When it comes to encoding, an enum value should fit within a varint, which is equivalent to a 32-bit integer, allowing for negative values. As a result, your maximum enum value could be lower than 0xFFFFFFFF.

However, the main challenge is that enum implementation varies across programming languages, meaning there's no unified underlying data type. In protobuf, open and closed enums are handled differently, with each language dealing with unknown values in its own way. You can read more about this in the protobuf programming guide on enums [here](https://protobuf.dev/programming-guides/enum/).

To sum up, there isn't a well-defined method for specifying the maximum value of an enum in protobuf, as the implementation is language-specific.